# How can I create and menage two and more tables with SQLite - Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am working on my Diploma work (Windows Phone 8 project), but unfortunately reached an impasse and don't have much time for more searching, so I beg you for help. I am using the following Tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-8-SQLite-96a1e43b. Everything here is clear, but can someone give me an example (where and how the code should be updated) how to create related table with one 'String' (City) for example, so I can display the data (in this case name and phone number) only for the chosen city.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you post what you have tried that didn't work?  Check [ask] for getting the most out of questions.

Comment: Thank you! Actually i haven't tried anything yet. I am using SQLite for the first time and don't have idea what to do (Furthermore i am not very good at programming) so i need the mentioned tutorial updated if possible. I am searching for information from a week, but still can't find detailed tutorial like this one, but with more than 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use SQLite-Net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)
You can install the library using Nuget and is very easy to use.

It has some limitations, but it will simplify the way you create tables, insert/read data, etc...

There are tons of documentation on How to use Sqlite-net...

Comment: Thank you, but as I already said, I am following this tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-8-SQLite-96a1e43b so SQLite-Net is already installed, but I can't find an example how to manage more than one table. Can you help?

Comment: Create a new table for you new Class, something like dbConn.CreateTable<City>();

Then, you can add cities using "dbConn.Insert(new City("New York"))" or read using "sbConn.Table<City>().Where(x=>x.Name == "New York")"

If you are looking for Foreign Keys... Sqlite-Net does not support them, but you can use other library like https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions to add them